# Using SSRS reporting services how to programmatically read subscription last run time and next send time

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

There are methods to create, update and delete subscriptions, get subscription properties  in SSRS reporting services but i didn't find a method that tells subscription last run time and next send time?

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you are asking how to set a subscription termination date and start date schedule or you want to review the logs for the last time the report was ran and the next time it is scheduled to run.

Comment: let me make it clear i have created a subscription for a report using report service method "CreateSubscription" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258083(v=sql.80).aspx). Now i need a method to get the above created subscription Last Executed time using the report service.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is that the next run time is stored in the MSDB job.

```
SELECT 
  c.Name AS ReportName
  , rs.ScheduleID AS JOB_NAME
  , s.[Description]
  , s.LastStatus
  , s.LastRunTime
  ,NextScheduledRun = CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(CAST(SC.next_run_date AS VARCHAR(255)),4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(CAST(SC.next_run_date AS VARCHAR(255)),5,2)+'-'+RIGHT(CAST(SC.next_run_date AS VARCHAR(255)),2)+ ' '+
    LEFT((RIGHT('0'+CAST(SC.next_run_time AS VARCHAR(6)),6)),2)+':'+SUBSTRING((RIGHT('0'+CAST(SC.next_run_time AS VARCHAR(6)),6)),3,2)+':'+RIGHT(SC.next_run_time,2))
  ,J.enabled
FROM 
  ReportServer..[Catalog] c 
  JOIN ReportServer..Subscriptions s ON c.ItemID = s.Report_OID 
  JOIN ReportServer..ReportSchedule rs ON c.ItemID = rs.ReportID
  AND rs.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID
  JOIN msdb..sysjobs J
  ON LTRIM(RTRIM(rs.ScheduleID)) = J.name
  JOIN  msdb..sysjobschedules AS SC
  ON SC.job_id = J.job_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to find last run time, but not next run time:

One way you can do this is to utilize a SQL query against the Report Server database.

In the Report Server, you can query the "Subscriptions" table. There is a column in there for "Last Run Time."

Run the query below against the SQL Report Server database to see what I am talking about.

You can utilize the value in the "Last Run Time" column.

```
 /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT [SubscriptionID]
      ,[OwnerID]
      ,[Report_OID]
      ,[Locale]
      ,[InactiveFlags]
      ,[ExtensionSettings]
      ,[ModifiedByID]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[Description]
      ,[LastStatus]
      ,[EventType]
      ,[MatchData]
      ,[LastRunTime]
      ,[Parameters]
      ,[DataSettings]
      ,[DeliveryExtension]
      ,[Version]
      ,[ReportZone]
  FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions]
```